# RemoteDisconnect using python request-html

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn web scraping in python with the request-html package. At first, I render a mainpage and pull out all the necessary links. That works just fine. Later I iterate over all links and render the specific subpage for that link. 2 Iterations are successful, but with the third I get an error that i am unable to solve.

Here is my code:

```py
# import HTMLSession from requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
baseurl = 'http://www.möbelfreude.de/'
resp = session.get(baseurl+'alle-boxspringbetten')

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()
links = resp.html.find('a.image-wrapper.text-center')

for link in links:
    print('Rendering... {}'.format(link.attrs['href']))

    r = session.get(baseurl + link.attrs['href'])
    r.html.render()

    print('Completed rendering... {}'.format(link.attrs['href']))

    # do stuff
```

Error:

````
Completed rendering... bett/boxspringbett-bea
Rendering... bett/boxspringbett-valina
Completed rendering... bett/boxspringbett-valina
Rendering... bett/boxspringbett-benno-anthrazit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 275, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the connection closure, and may be due to some configurations on the server side.

Have you scraping the site and appending the links to a list.

Then request each link individually to find and locate the specific directory that is cause issue.

Using dev mode in chrome under the network tab can help identify the necessary headers for requests that require them.